# Enum's parameter is always set to null

Tags: java, oop, enums

I have two classes, `FruitPlant` and `Fruit`, and each one have their own `Type` enum:

```
public class FruitPlant extends Plant {
    public static enum Type {
        // Dry-hot 
        PEACH_TREE("peach", 3, 80, Fruit.Type.PEACH),
        CACTUS("cactus", 10000, 120, Fruit.Type.PRICKLYPEAR), 

        // Dry-cool
        BLUEBERRY_BUSH("blueberry", 3, 40, Fruit.Type.BLUEBERRY),
        CHERRY_TREE("cherry", 3, 60, Fruit.Type.CHERRY), 

        // Wet-hot
        ORANGE_TREE("orange", 2, 80, Fruit.Type.ORANGE),
        MELON_VINE("melon", 1.5, 80, Fruit.Type.MELON), 

        // Wet-cool
        APPLE_TREE("apple", 2, 60, Fruit.Type.APPLE), 
        STRAWBERRY_BUSH("strawberry", 1.5, 60, Fruit.Type.STRAWBERRY);

        public double waterHardiness;
        public int preferedTemp;
        public int[] babyImage;
        public int[] childImage;
        public int[] subAdultImage;
        public int[] adultImage;
        public int[] pregnantImage;
        public Fruit.Type fruitType;

        Type (String imagePath, double waterHardiness, int preferedTemp, Fruit.Type fruitType){
            this.waterHardiness = waterHardiness;
            this.preferedTemp = preferedTemp;
            babyImage = Image.loadImage("/res/plants/" + imagePath + "/baby.png");
            childImage = Image.loadImage("/res/plants/" + imagePath + "/child.png");
            subAdultImage = Image.loadImage("/res/plants/" + imagePath + "/subadult.png");
            adultImage = Image.loadImage("/res/plants/" + imagePath + "/adult.png");
            pregnantImage = Image.loadImage("/res/plants/" + imagePath + "/pregnant.png");
            this.fruitType = fruitType;
        }
    }

    Type type;
    public FruitPlant(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
        System.out.println(type.fruitType); // Prints whatever Fruit.Type the FruitPlant.Type has
    }
}
```

```
public class Fruit implements Element, Holdable, Plantable {
    public static enum Type {
        PRICKLYPEAR(FruitPlant.Type.CACTUS), 
        PEACH(FruitPlant.Type.PEACH_TREE),
        CHERRY(FruitPlant.Type.CHERRY_TREE), 
        BLUEBERRY(FruitPlant.Type.BLUEBERRY_BUSH),
        MELON(FruitPlant.Type.MELON_VINE), 
        ORANGE(FruitPlant.Type.ORANGE_TREE),
        APPLE(FruitPlant.Type.APPLE_TREE), 
        STRAWBERRY(FruitPlant.Type.STRAWBERRY_BUSH);


        public FruitPlant.Type plant;

        Type(FruitPlant.Type plant) {
            System.out.println(plant);
            this.plant = plant;
        }
    }

    Type type;
    public Fruit(Type type){
        this.type = type;
        System.out.println(type.plant); // Prints null
    }
}
```

And some tester code as required:

```
public class Main {
    public static void Main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Next line printed should be BLUEBERRY:");
        FruitPlant blueberryBush = new FruitPlant(FruitPlant.Type.BLUEBERRY_BUSH);
        System.out.println("Next line printed should be BLUEBERRY_BUSH:");
        Fruit blueberry = new Fruit(Fruit.Type.BLUEBERRY);
        System.out.println("End test");

    }
}
```

Whenever I make a `FruitPlant` object and pass it a `FruitPlant.Type` enum in a `FruitPlant` constructor, the `fruit` field of that enum returns me a `Fruit.Type` enum. However, Whenever I make a `Fruit` object and give it a `Fruit.Type` enum in a `Fruit` constructor, the `plant` field of that enum always evaluates to `null`.

Does this have to do with the circularity of the system? Why does the `Fruit.Type.plant` field return `null` while the `FruitPlant.Type.fruit` returns a `Fruit.Type enum`?

PS: There are more to these two classes, but I've cut most of it out as they are irrelevant. I also used skeleton classes with type enums because most of the fruit plants and fruit behave similarly, and it felt wrong to make 8 mostly identical classes.

Comment: *"... the plant field of that enum always evaluates to null."* Please edit the question to include a [mcve], i.e. a main method which demonstrates the erroneous behaviour, the output, and the expected output.

Comment: @kaya3 Absolutely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem occurs because you have two enums, `Fruit.Type` and `FruitPlant.Type`, both of which reference each other in their constant declarations:

```java
public class FruitPlant extends Plant {
    public static enum Type {
        // Dry-hot 
        PEACH_TREE("peach", 3, 80, Fruit.Type.PEACH),
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}

// ...
public class Fruit implements Element, Holdable, Plantable {
    public static enum Type {
        // ...
        PEACH(FruitPlant.Type.PEACH_TREE),
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

The enum constants `Fruit.Type.PEACH` and `FruitPlant.Type.PEACH_TREE` have to be instantiated before they can be used.

Suppose `PEACH` is instantiated first; then `FruitPlant.Type.PEACH_TREE` is not instantiated yet, so the static member of that name has its default initial value of `null`. The object it would reference does not exist yet, so there can be no reference to it. On the other hand, if `PEACH_TREE` is instantiated first, then it cannot acquire a reference to `PEACH` because that object doesn't exist yet; the enum member which will refer to it currently has its default initial value of `null`.

The solution is to delay the circular references between these enums until all the enum constants have been initialised; you can write methods `getPlant` and `getFruit` which return the right value, instead of storing them as fields. At the time these methods are called, all of the enum constants will have been instantiated so there will be no default `null` values due to uninitialised members.

```java
public class FruitPlant extends Plant {
    public static enum Type {
        PEACH_TREE("peach", 3, 80),
        // ...

        public Fruit.Type getFruit() {
            switch(this) {
                case PEACH_TREE: return Fruit.Type.PEACH;
                // ...
                default: throw new IllegalStateException();
            }
        }

        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```